# JQuery replaced link not working under IE 8-10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I made a popup and I have a problem with IE 8-10 (under IE11 no problem). My code replace an image to linked image. Link is working under Firefox, Chrome and IE11, but not working under other IE versions. This is a popop window by default. Here is my code:

```
<div id="fadeinboxrevol">
<div id="koppbase">
<p class="kalapacs"><img src="./images/original.png" alt="Click here" /></p>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tto = jQuery.noConflict();
function get_path() {
var piclist =['./images/1.png','./images/2.png','./images/3.png','./images/4.png'];
var linklist =['1.html','2.html','3.html','4.html'];
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*piclist.length);
var picpath = piclist[random];
var linkpath = linklist[random];
var pack = [picpath, linkpath];

return pack;
}

tto(".kalapacs").click(function () {
var mypack = get_path();
var mypic = mypack[0];
var mypath = mypack[1];

var content1 = '<p class="torp"><img class="torve" src="'+mypic+'" alt="Don't wait" /><a class="tortext" href="'+mypath+'"></a></p>';

tto("#koppbase").html(content1);

});

</script>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#fadeinboxrevol {
position: absolute;
width: auto;
left: 301px;
top: 262.5px;
visibility: visible;
border: none;
background-color: ;
padding: 0 px;
z-index: 999;
text-align: left;
}
.kalapacs:hover {
cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/others/oth-5/oth438.cur), progress !important;
}
.torp {
position: relative;
}
.tortext {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
display: block;
z-index: 9999;
}
#revolclosebutton {
margin-top: -40px;
right: 20px;
position: absolute;
width: 16px;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Here is an example in jsfiddle, I use jQuery 1.11 version for better compatibility:
http://jsfiddle.net/mykee/uDCKL/

I tried this line too:

```
tto("#koppbase").replaceWith(content1);
```

but not helped. :-(

What's my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line of code: `var content1 = '<p class="torp"><img class="torve" src="'+mypic+'" alt="Don't wait" /><a class="tortext" href="'+mypath+'"></a></p>';`

**Change it to:** `var content1 = '<p class="torp"><a class="tortext" href="'+mypath+'"><img class="torve" src="'+mypic+'" alt="Don't wait" /></a></p>';`

When you look at older IE the a is empty after the img tag, so its hard to click it! (Hover down the 2nd image.)

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uDCKL/7/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! Changed content1 line to this:

```
var content = '<p class="torp"><a class="tortext" href="'+mypath+'"><img class="torve" src="'+mypic+'" alt="Dont wait" /></a></p>';
```

And CSS replaced with this and working:

```
.kalapacs:hover {
cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/others/oth-5/oth438.cur), progress !important;
}
.torp {
position: relative;
}
.tortext {
display: block;
}
#revolclosebutton {
margin-top: -40px;
right: 20px;
position: absolute; 
width: 16px;
z-index: 99999;
}
```